# AngularJS ng-model issue

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue in Angular 1.6.

I have a table with data populated

TABLE HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="loc in loca" ng-click="edit(loc)">
 <td>{{loc.name}}</td>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.loca = data; //Fetched from remote

$scope.edit = function(locobj){
  $scope.newLocObj = locobj;
}
```

HTML

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="newLocObj.name" />
```

What basically happening is that when I click the table row, the data of that row get populated in the textbox, which is fine and working as expected.

But whenever I try to edit the data in the textbox, the data in HTML TABLE also gets same value as that of the textbox.

How to refrain from that?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Make a plunker please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because the values are pointing to the same reference. Use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to create a deep copy of the object

```
$scope.edit = function(locobj){
  $scope.newLocObj = angular.copy(locobj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use angular.copy() instead of assigning

```
$scope.edit = function(locobj){
        $scope.newLocObj = angular.copy(locobj);
      }
```

> angular.copy() performs a deep copy (cf. "clone") of the argument -
>   essentially creating a new object - whereas using the assignment
>   operator = just assigns reference's.